# Customer Access Token

Tags: magento-2.1, token

I am trying to get the customers Access Token while they are logged in to our `Magento 2.1.8` site while using a custom module I am developing.

I have been following the official Magento 2 tutorials to do this and it says that to get the token I must send the user's `username` and `password` to the appropriate API endpoint. When the Access Token is required, the user is already signed in.

How do I get the logged in users Customers Access Token without using their Username and Password?

Magento 2 Tutorial:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/order-tutorial/order-create-customer.html

Answer (score 0):

Searching around a bit from when I was trying to get around the "/me" endpoint 'fix'.

This may help - https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/REST-API-call-to-get-logged-in-customer-ID/m-p/62092/highlight/true#M1813